# Changing Layout of Product Archive Woo Commerce

Tags: php, html, css, hook-woocommerce

We have been trying to customize the layout of our Woo commerce site.

On the archive page we have the below data being displayed vertically for each product displayed .

Image
Title 
Price
Short Description

We are trying to display the Image on the Left and the 3 other data points on the right for each product.

Any help would be appreciated.

I'v only been researching at this point. Based on what i'v read i have to use hooks..

I assume i would just put those hooks to a

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">IMAGE HOOK</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
TITLEHOOK 
PRICEHOOK  
SHORT-DESCRIPTIONHOOK
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried anything so far? Can we see how your HTML & CSS look like?

Comment: Please could you edit the question and paste this information there? It would help others answer your question

Comment: Fixed the comment... Sorry